# Converting a large number of MP3 files to videos for YouTube, each using same the JPEG image

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I am looking for a way to convert large number of MP3 files to videos, each using the same image. Efficient processing time is important.

I tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -vcodec libx264 video.mp4
```

[VLC media player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) played the resulting video file with the correct sound, but a blank screen.

[Microsoft Media Player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player) played the sound and showed the intended image. I uploaded the video to YouTube and received the message:

> "The video has failed to process. Please make sure you are uploading a supported file type."

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create video:

   ```
   ffmpeg -framerate 6 -loop 1 -i input.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -t 00:10:00 video.mp4
   ```

   The duration (`-t`) should be ≥ the MP3 with the longest duration.
2. Now stream copy the same video for each MP3:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -movflags +faststart -shortest output.mp4
   ```

Some notes regarding compatibility:

- MP3 in MP4 does not have universal support, but will be fine in YouTube. If your target players do not like it then add `-c:a aac` after `-c copy` to output AAC audio.
- If your target player does not like it then increase the `-framerate` value or add the `-r` output option with an appropriate value, such as `-r 15`. Again, YouTube should be able to handle it.

Comment: Excellent solution!

Creation of the the image only video for batch processing takes long - in my case about 43 minutes for about 1:20:00 duration video.
After it was created used it with 14 MP3 files adding audio to create 14 actual videos which upload successfully to YouTube. 
Adding sound took about 4 seconds per MP3.

Thank you very much!